# Cannot find seg fault error in Singly Linked List Insert Method

Tags: c++, debugging, insert, segmentation-fault, singly-linked-list

I'm trying to implement a SortedList class which uses a singly-linked list. This list is sorted by a Student ID number which can be retrieved from the student class (and a student object is passed in as a parameter in this method). When calling my insert method I'm getting a seg fault error. I've tried debugging with the linux terminal and some print lines but I cannot nail down exactly where the error is.

With the current code the last cout<< that prints is "Created list nodes" so most of the code doesn't execute. If someone could help me find the errors in my ways it would be greatly appreciated!!

```
// insterts a student into the list in a sorted manner according to their ID
```

bool SortedList::insert(Student *s){

```
// need to have in order of smallest student ID to Largest.

struct Listnode *newNode, *curr;
curr = head;

cout << "Created list nodes" << endl;

// first check if the list is empty, if so add to head's next
if(curr->next == NULL){
    //newNode->student = s; // give the new node the parameter student
    head->next = newNode; // assign the head to the (now) first node in list
    cout << "Added first node in list empty if" << endl;
    return true; // return indicating that the student was added
}

if(find(s->getID()) != NULL){ // if a student is found, return false 
    return false;
}

cout << "Finished find student check, wasn't found" << endl; 

int counter = 1;

while(curr->student->getID() > s->getID() && curr->next != NULL){ // iterate through list to find proper spot in sorted list by checkin ID
    cout << "Executed loop " << counter << " times" << endl;
    counter++;
    curr = curr->next; // advance curr
}

cout << "Finished while loop" << endl;

newNode->student = s; // store the student in the node
newNode->next = curr-> next; // set the new nodes next value in the chain
curr->next = newNode; // link the node before the new node, to the new node
return true; // return true since the new node was added
```

}

Comment: What's the initial value of `head`?

Comment: The above is not an example that can be used directly to reproduce the error; voting to close.

Comment: I would guess that in your case `curr==head==nullptr`

Comment: Right at the top `head->next = newNode;`, `newnode` is a junk pointer pointing nowhere.

Comment: You never assign a value to `newNode`, so that can cause a segfault when you access it as a pointer.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Learning to prepare a [minimal complete example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) isn't just a courtesy to us, it's a vital programming skill that can be of immense help tho you in tracking down bugs like these.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is what if your head is `NULL` then your statement `curr->next` is invalid memory location. Thats why you are getting a segmentation fault.Rather just do `if(curr==NULL)`.And assign student to the `curr`.